# Programmatically generate VersionOne reports for multiple projects

Tags: reporting, versionone

My organization is tracking multiple Scrum projects in VersionOne.  Each week, we use the Release Forecasting report for each project to create a management dashboard that indicates the health and expected completion date of each project.  I would like to automate this.  Do any of the VersionOne APIs allow for the execution of this report and retrieving the image that is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to automate the retrieval of this report, but not through the V1 API.  Through careful use of Fiddler and a C# script using WebClient to execute POST requests, it was possible.  The resulting code is pretty fragile, though, since it isn't using the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an endpoint specific to Release Forecasting. Nor is there an endpoint to generate the image. However, you can get to the underlying data via the existing API endpoints. For reporting, I recommend [query.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1). The closest example is [the query for burndown data](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Query_for_Burndown_Data). You would need to take `Scope` as the focus of the query, not `Timebox`.

You might also take a look at VersionOne's [Reporting and Analytics](http://www.versionone.com/product/agile-reporting-and-analytics/). While that is not a coding or API way to get the reports, it might still automate the needs you have.